# ActiveModelをform_forに使えない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class NewsArticleSearchCondition
 include ActiveModel::Model
 attr_accessor :keywords
end
```

上記の`ActiveModel::Model`を`include`するクラスがあったとして、これを検索フォームに利用したいと考えています。そこでコントローラで初期化して使ってみました。

```
def index
  @search_condition = NewsArticleSearchCondition.new
end
```

ヴューも見よう見まねで用意してみました。

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<%= form_for @search_condition, url: search_news_articles_path do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :keywords %>
 <%= f.submit '検索' %>
<% end %>
```

ページの表示に問題はないものの、検索を実行すると失敗でした。
`ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty)`というエラーが出てくるのですが、コントローラで明らかにオブジェクトを生成しているのに`nil`か空のオブジェクトが指定されていると指摘されており、困惑しています。
使い方のどこが間違っているのか分かりません。ご教示お願いします。

rails 4.1.4
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
OS: CentOS 6.6

```
I, [2015-11-30T13:33:53.767016 #19474]  INFO -- : Started POST "/master/news_articles/search" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-11-30 13:33:53 +0000
I, [2015-11-30T13:33:53.769260 #19474]  INFO -- : Processing by NewsArticlesController#search as HTML
I, [2015-11-30T13:33:53.770050 #19474]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?", "authenticity_token"=>"2Vgd2hKSsyLBhoYOUU4xN2ufoYfNZ42cfRBt8CdVoN8=", "news_article_search_condition"=>{"keywords"=>"sss"}, "commit"=>"検索"}
I, [2015-11-30T13:33:53.807700 #19474]  INFO -- :   Rendered news_articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (30.7ms)
I, [2015-11-30T13:33:53.808130 #19474]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms
F, [2015-11-30T13:33:53.809900 #19474] FATAL -- :
ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty):
    1: <h1>Title</h1>
    2: <%= form_for @search_condition, url: search_news_articles_path do |f| %>
    3:   <%= f.text_field :keywords %>
    4:   <%= f.submit '検索' %>
    5: <% end %>
  app/views/news_articles/index.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_news_articles_index_html_erb___2506405902150851388_75157400'
  app/controllers/news_articles_controller.rb:88:in `search'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コードが無いので推測になりますが、`NewsArticlesController#search` の中で `@search_condition` を設定していないのだと思います。

Comment: ログの見方を間違っていました。#searchが実行されて、そこで、仰るように、変数設定をしてなかったです。それで、ヴューの処理で失敗していたのですね。